# If $q|\frac{x^5-2^5}{x-2}$ then $q=1 \mod5$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove if $q$ is prime and in the form of $4k-1$ and  $q\mid\frac{x^5-2^5}{x-2} $ then $ q\equiv1 \mod 5$

Comment: if $x=4$ then we note that $2\,|\,496$.  Taking $x=17$ we note that $5\,|\,94655$

Comment: pay attention to " if "

Comment: I don't understand.  Letting $F(x)=\frac {x^5-32}{x-2}$ My observations show that $2\,|\,F(4)$ and $5\,|\,F(17)$.  Either of those appears to disprove your claim.

Comment: you should prove $ q\equiv1 \ Mod 5$

Comment: I don't understand.  I can't prove it because it is not true.  $2\not \equiv 1 \pmod 5$ and $5\not \equiv 1 \pmod 5$.

Comment: Ok. I added  a little supposition  in question.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is downvoted. It is an extremely legit and elegant elementary number theory problem. 

It is really messed up to see that, all elementary/olympiadic problems are getting downvotes in this website.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, $q\mid x^5-2^5$, that is, $x^5\equiv 2^5\pmod{q}$. Now, observe that, if $x\equiv 2\pmod{5}$, then $q\mid 80$, which is not possible as $q\equiv -1\pmod{4}$. Hence, $x\not\equiv 2\pmod{5}$. This means, if we let $a\equiv x2^{-1}\pmod{q}$, then $a^5\equiv 1\pmod{q}$, and $a\not\equiv 1\pmod{q}$. Now, let $d$ be the smallest positive integer for which $a^d\equiv 1\pmod{q}$.

It is well known that $d\mid 5$ and $d\nmid 1$. Therefore, $d=5$. Finally, since $q$ is a prime, we have, by Fermat's theorem, that $a^{q-1}\equiv 1\pmod{q}$, hence, $5=d\mid q-1$, which is the claim.

Answer (score -1):

Clearly, $x\not\equiv2\pmod q\ \ \ \ (1)$

Let $x\equiv2y\pmod q\implies y^5\equiv1\pmod q$ for odd prime $q$

$\implies(5,q-1)\mid$ord$_qy$

If $5\nmid(q-1),(5,q-1)=1\implies1\mid$ord$_qy\implies$ord$_qy=1\implies y^1\equiv1\pmod q$

$\implies x\equiv2q\equiv2\pmod q$ which contradicts $(1)$

Comment: I have two question. First why $x \not\equiv 2 (mod q)$. Second what is y?

Comment: @MichaelBrockhausen, Observe that $q$ divides $y^5-2^5$. What are the roots of $y^5-2^5=0$  and those of $$\dfrac{y^5-2^5}{y-2}=0$$  For the second question, $x\equiv2y\pmod q$